# Can a day partitioned table be changed to clustered table?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have read the docs regarding the same, but can't seem to find anything stating clearly on above.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify the existing table, but you could write a query overwriting the existing one.

See https://medium.com/google-cloud/bigquery-optimized-cluster-your-tables-65e2f684594b

```
CREATE TABLE `fh-bigquery.wikipedia_v3.pageviews_2017`
PARTITION BY DATE(datehour)
CLUSTER BY wiki, title
OPTIONS(
   description="Wikipedia pageviews - partitioned by day, clustered by (wiki, title). Contact https://twitter.com/felipehoffa"
   , require_partition_filter=true
)
AS SELECT * FROM `fh-bigquery.wikipedia_v2.pageviews_2017`
WHERE datehour > '1990-01-01' # nag
```

Comment: Instead of using query output to overwrite existing table, can we use extract and load sequence to do the same?  I'm asking this because I tried same by exporting ingestion-time day partitioned table to gcs bucket first, and then loading it back into the same table, with new configuration: day partitioning on given field, and clustering on given field. It doesn't work. I get this error =>  Incompatible table partitioning specification. Expects partitioning specification interval(type:day), but input partitioning specification is interval(type:day,field:event_time) clustering(event_name)

Answer (score 1):

The API now allows adding clustering to an existing table if the table is partitioned. Unfortunately, you can only do this through one of the APIs, it doesn't seem possible through "bq".

Here's an example in Java:

```
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQuery;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryException;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryOptions;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.Clustering;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.Field;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.FieldList;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.LegacySQLTypeName;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.Schema;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.StandardTableDefinition;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.StandardTableDefinition.Builder;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.Table;
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SetClustering {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String datasetName = args[0];
    String tableId = args[1];
    String columnName = args[2];
    setClusterByColumn(columnName, datasetName, tableId);
  }

  public static void setClusterByColumn(String columnName, String datasetName, String tableId) {
    try {
      BigQuery bigquery = BigQueryOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();

      Table table = bigquery.getTable(datasetName, tableId);

      StandardTableDefinition definition = table.getDefinition();
      StandardTableDefinition newDefinition = definition.toBuilder()
        .setClustering(Clustering.newBuilder().setFields(ImmutableList.of("event_name")).build())
        .build();

      // Update the table with the new definition
      Table updatedTable =
          table.toBuilder().setDefinition(newDefinition).build();
      updatedTable.update();
      System.out.println("Clustering successfully added to table");
    } catch (BigQueryException e) {
      System.out.println("Clustering column was not added. \n" + e.toString());
    }
  }
}
```